# Inverse of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I am trying to find the inverse of this function (where it have an inverse )

Let $A , B $ two real numbers different from zeros
what is the inverse of this function $$F:=x \rightarrow A\sin(x)+B x\cos(x)$$
we can choose in intervalle in $(0,\pi/2)$ in which $F^{'}(t)\neq 0$

Let's start to find the inverse
$$x=A\sin(y)+bx\cos(y)$$
differentiationwith respect to $x$ gives :
$$1=Ay'\cos(y)+B\cos(y)-Bxy'\sin(y)$$
this gives $$y'=\dfrac{1-B\cos(y)}{A\cos(y)-Bx\sin(y)}$$
and from this point I don't know how to solve this equation (Find $y$ in terms of x )

Comment: This function does not have a closed form inverse.

Comment: thank you @PeterForeman could you explain why or give me a reference?

Comment: Typically any function involving the product or division of trigonometric and polynomial functions doesn't have a closed form inverse. It's an intuitive notion as for example $x\sin{(x)}$ alone is not invertible using standard functions.